# Re-feeding a variable into a looped function

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I'm attempting to make a simple program for encoding things in base64 multiple times (not really for any particular reason, just more as an example and practice).  I've been having quite a bit of trouble though, it could be because I've not had enough (or possibly had too much) coffee.

I can't seem to figure out how to refeed my variable (text) back into the function that encodes it until `i` is equal to `times`

Any assistance with this would be appreciated!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        function encodeThis(text,times) {
            var toEncode = text;
            for (var i = 0; i < times, i++) {
                btoa(toEncode);
            }
            document.getElementById("result").value = toEncode;
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <b>Text to Encode</b><br/>
        <input type="text" id="encode"><br/>
        <b>Number of Times to Encode (Integers Only)<br/>
        <input type="text" id="times">
        <button type="submit" onclick="encodeThis(encode,times)">Test</button>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <b>Result</b><br/>
        <input type="text" id="result">
    </body>
</html>
```

Would I need to put a function inside of that function to refeed the variable in?

Comment: I think it should be `toEncode = btoa(toEncode);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the result of the encoding back to the variable.

```
function encodeThis(text, times) {
  var toEncode = text;
  for (var i = 0; i < times, i++) {
    toEncode = btoa(toEncode);
  }
  document.getElementById("result").value = toEncode;
}
```

---

But in terms of the overall code in your example you also need to actually get the text from the `#encode` and the `#times` elements and fix the syntax error in the `for` loop.

So

```js
function encodeThis(text, times) {
  var toEncode = text.value, // read the value from the encode input element
    numTimes = parseInt(times.value, 10); // read the value from the times element and convert to number

  for (var i = 0; i < numTimes; i++) {
    toEncode = btoa(toEncode);
  }
  document.getElementById("result").value = toEncode;
}
```

```html
<b>Text to Encode</b><br/>
<input type="text" id="encode" /><br/>
<b>Number of Times to Encode (Integers Only)</b><br/>
<input type="text" id="times" />
<button type="submit" onclick="encodeThis(encode,times)">Test</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<b>Result</b><br/>
<input type="text" id="result">
```

Comment: @MarkisCook i have just added an update that fixes some more basic issues.

Comment: This absolutely worked.  Thanks a lot.  I didn't know that you'd have to put in a text.value and a times.value to record the information!  In addition, it seems I had quite a few synthax errors against me as well.  Great answer, thanks a lot!